# Getting changed file path with launchd in Mountain Lion

Tags: launchd, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using launchd to watch a directory for file changes. This works fine, but I need to supply the file path to the changed file when the program executes.

How do I obtain the file path? Are there variables available within launchd?